How is the satyrical phrase "Vae me, puto concacavi me!" by Seneca the Younger grammatical? Shouldn't it be "Vae mihi, puto me concacavisse!"?
Seneca the Younger had a satyrical phrase: "Vae me, puto concacavi me." (Oh dear, I think I have shitted myself.). But it appears to be rather ungrammatical. "Vae" goes with dative, right? As in Vercingetorix'es phrase "Vae victis!". Furthermore, in Classical Latin, you would you use accusative with infinitive to express this: "Vae mihi, puto me concacavisse.". Or, in Late Latin, you would use quia+indicative for that, like this: "Vae mihi, puto quia concacavi me.". Or was there a period of Latin in which such a phrase wouldn't sound very ungrammatical?

You should really get into the habit of checking a dictionary when you come across something odd. This applies to this question, the recent one on quando, and many others. E.g. L&S contains both answers in the relevant entries, and any other good dictionary will do as well. Doing a quick dictionary check-up and sharing your thoughts is also likely to improve your questions' reception.

should be "satirical."   There was a word satyrical, having characteristics  of a satyr, as in a lecher

From the OLD's entry for uae:

...CONSTS.: esp. w. dat., rarely acc., of person concerned.

So the accusative is sometimes used instead of the dative. Another example is Catullus 8.15 (scelesta, vae te)
The copies of the text that I have surround puto with commas, to mark it as parenthetical, so accusative+infinitive isn't required.

'uae me, puto, concacaui me'


I wonder if this parenthetical "puto" originated as a shortened version of "ut puto."
